# Android getInputStream.ReadBoolean issue

Tags: php, android, sql, boolean, datainputstream

I'm doing an SQL-query from a PHP-script, that echo's 1 if succesful and 0 if not. This is just echo'ed in the body.

To send the information i wanna query in the database, I'm using this:
(This is an Android project, using AsyncTask and the issue is in the 'new' thread, created with doInBackground)

```
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
        String request = "PHP-file-location";
        URL url = new URL(request); 
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false); 
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
        connection.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setUseCaches (false);

        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        os.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        ... continues.
```

The PHP-script handles the information (this part works - checked with .html form) and echo's the 0 or 1, that I now wanna pick up in my Android-application:

```
DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        boolean response = is.readBoolean();
        is.close();
        connection.disconnect();

        if(is!=null)
            is.close();
        if(os!=null)
            os.close();
        return response;
```

But for some reason it says the value is true, both if 0 or 1. Am i using readBoolean wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong. The response is a plain text... You should be using something like this:

```
reader = new InputStreamReader (connection.getInputStream());
        int c = reader.read();
        if (c == '0') {

        } else if (c == '1') {

        }
```

remember closing the stream after done.

I dont understand very well what you´re doing with the body and the url parameters... Anyway. DataOutput and DataInput streams are for writing and reading binary serializations of objects, don´t play too much with them if you want your interfaces to be compatible with other clients/programming languages.

Comment: Thanks! .read returns 48 if 0 and 49 if 1. I suppose that's ASCII or something, but it works. :-)